# "Эмиссия доллара" или "эмиссия долларов"?

Tags: склонение

Как сказать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмиссия доллара. "Доллар" здесь валюта, а не конкретные банкноты или платежные средства. Множественного числа не имеет. Хотя, конечно, хорошо бы контекст. Если там конкретные суммы, то возможны варианты.

Comment: В передаче "Диалог с Михаилом Хазиным" на РБК собеседник сказал: "Очередная новая эмиссия долларов она (неразборчиво). Либо эти доллары останутся у банков, либо уйдут..."

Comment: Я бы здесь сказал "доллара". Хотя в сочетании с последующим "доллары" и множественное число не выглядит ошибкой...
Сейчас в экономических кругах справлюсь.

Короче, ничего я не понял, всё, говорят, плохо. В принципе возможно "эмиссия доллара" (как валюты) или "эмиссия долларов" (как конкретных купюр или монет). Но по контексту тут скорее просто "выпуск". Эмиссия - конретная экономическая процедура, а не просто запуск печатного станка. Как понял, ногами не бейте.

Comment: Ох уж эти экономисты! Сами путаются и людей путают. Спасибо.